# context sensitive tokenization of code

Tags: parsing, token, tokenize, formal-languages

I am working on a parser for a language that has

- identifiers (say, a letter followed by a number of alphanumeric characters or an underscore),
- integers (any number of digits and possibly carets `^`),
- some operators,
- filename (a number of alphanumeric characters and possibly slashes, and dots)

Apparently filename overlaps integers and identifiers, so in general I cannot decide if I have a filename or, say, an identifier unless the filename contains a slash or a dot.

But filename can only follow a specific operator.

My question is how this situation is usually handled during tokenization? I have a table driven tokenizer (lexer), but I am not sure how to tell a filename from either an integer or an identifier. How is this done?

If filename was a superset of integers and identifiers then I probably could have grammar productions that could handle that, but the tokens overlap...

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a tokenizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex and other lexers have the concept of [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html). Essentially the lexer is a state machine and its exact behaviour will depend on its current state.

In your example, when your lexer encounters the operator preceding a filename it should switch to a `FilenameMode` state (or whatever) and then switch back once it has produced the filename token it was expecting.

EDIT:

Just to give some concrete code this side of the hyperlink:

You would trigger your `FILENAME_MODE` when you encounter the operator...

```
{FILENAME_PREFIX} { BEGIN(FILENAME_MODE); }
```

You would define your rule to parse a filename:

```
<FILENAME_MODE>{FILENAME_CHARS}+ { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
```

...switching back to the `INITIAL` state in the action.